# Перенос логики работы с БД из серверной части в клиентскую

Tags: javascript, node.js, java-ee, клиент-сервер

Возник неоднозначный вопрос касательно клиент-серверной архитектуры:

**Вводные**:

1. Пишет все 1 разработчик (backend и frontend).
2. Единица измерения эффективности - время разработки (например, изменить код в клиенте быстрее, чем изменить его на клиенте и сервере).

---

В большинстве сайтов\приложений, которые я пишу, прослеживается следующая логика:

- **Клиент** - несет в себе логику отображения данных. Например, при нажатии кнопки - клиент запрашивает у сервера список объектов (передавая в параметрах запроса параметры выборки) и затем отображает клиенту.
- **Сервер** - несет логику "прослойки" между БД и клиентом, предоставляя роуты доступа (с методами для работы с GET, POST и т.д). Например, сервер получает запрос `GET https://domain.com/users` с параметрами выборки (offset, columns), парсит эти параметры в SQL запрос, достает из БД список пользователей и возвращает обратно клиенту.
- **Сервер** - хранит данные. Здесь понятно.

В какой-то момент я пришел к выводу, что клиент и сервер дублируют логику друг друга. Условно говоря, клиент имеет функционал для доступа к URL'y `/users/` (с методам `getUsers()`, `removeUser(id)` и т.д.), а сервер предоставляет роуты (с методам `get(users), delete(user)` и т.д.) для работы с таблицей `users`.

---

Ради интереса, я изменил логику сервера, чтобы был только один роут доступа к данным: `https://domain.com/database`.

В качестве параметров, этот роут принимает:

1. Название таблиц(-ы) (в нашем случае `users`, но можно сделать и `join`).
2. Параметры для выборки данных (метод select\delete\etc., параметры where, offset, sort и т.д. в виде JSON-объекта).
3. Данные пользователя. При запросе через этот роут, сервер проверяет, авторизован ли пользователь и имеет ли он доступ к таблицам (например, пользователь с правами `user` может получить только доступ к базе `users`, но не к `staff` и т.д.).

При каждом запросе проверяется авторизация и проверка параметров на SQL-инъекцию (чтобы не прошел параметр `method: "SELECT * FROM users; -- "`).

В результате, если раньше сервер имел логику настройки роутов и проверки данных - отпала логика настройки роутов и дублирования методов GET, POST и т.д. для каждой таблицы. Теперь есть только 3 универсальных метода `GET POST DELETE` для всей базы данных.

---

Однако, видимо, есть причины, почему такая практика не получила распространения. Первая мысль - возможны проблемы с защитой. Но авторизация и проверка данных на SQL инъекции осталась. Грубо говоря, разницы между двумя вариантами в плане защиты нет.

**Вопрос:** почему так не делают? Какие минусы у такого подхода, что может пойти не так и следует ли дальше использовать такой подход?

**Возможный ответ:** почему нельзя! Можно! Есть же [Google Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/?hl=ru)!

**Уточнение:** вопрос довольно объемный и однозначного ответа нет. Поэтому готов обсуждать любые утверждения в ответах\комментариях, чтобы "дойти" до истины.

Comment: и в скольких процентах случаев нужны выборки из отдельных таблиц? в 3? 5?

Comment: @teran, не стал упоминать в сообщении, но есть доп. параметр `join`, где указываются доп. таблицы. В общем, выборки из нескольких таблиц тоже можно делать. Сейчас поправлю в посте.

Comment: А что делать в вашем случае если нужна специальная бизнес логика, например, при регистрации пользователя слать сообщение на почту?

Comment: У вас всегда заранее все детали бизнес задачи известны?

Comment: @Ghost, "почта" - тогда из клиента обращусь на сервер с указанием отправить письмо. "бизнес-задачи" - по мере развития, буду добавлять логику в клиент так же, как и добавлял бы ее в сервер. Но вариант интересные. Добавьте в ответ, потом резюмируем все в один ответ

Comment: @RostislavDugin вы начинаете слишком много доверять клиенту.

Comment: @andreymal, а что значит "слишком много" и... почему нет?

Comment: @RostislavDugin потому что клиент полностью подконтролен пользователю и может быть отредактирован пользователем на свой вкус. Захотел — не отправил письмо, захотел — вместо нормального письма отправил спам. Клиент должен выполнять необходимый минимум допустимых действий, и все его запросы должны тщательно проверяться сервером. Если по логике нужно обязательно отправить письмо после какого-то действия — нужно брать и сразу отправлять письмо на сервере, а не дожидаться реаккции клиента, ведь его можно никогда и не дождаться.

Comment: @andreymal, слишком специфический кейс. Слишком. Никто не будет "не отправлять письмо себе". Речь идет только о работе с данными. Момент "отправить письмо через сервер" - проверяется сервером. Чтобы человек не мог отправить письмо другому человеку, например.

Comment: @RostislavDugin ну и зачем делать такие вещи на клиенте, если всё равно всё проверяется сервером? Пусть сервер целиком и занимается. Вы как-то странно нерационально мыслите

Comment: @andreymal, но сервер не отвечает за бизнес-логику (когда и зачем что-то делает). Он просто дает функцию, которую клиент использует в подконтрольной ему бизнес-логике.

Comment: @RostislavDugin а он должен отвечать за бизнес-логику, потому что, во-первых, клиенты полностью подконтрольны пользователям (см. выше), а во-вторых, после ваших изменений клиенты будут обновляться не мгновенно (особенно если это не вкладки в браузере, а приложения на iOS/Android), и в итоге вы получите много разных клиентов с разной бизнес-логикой, которые обновятся неизвестно когда. Зачем такие сложности, когда можно просто делать всё на сервере?

Comment: @andreymal, как Вы написали под ответом - действительно, вопрос поддержки большого кол-ва клиентов существует. Как я сказал - я считаю, что он самый весомый из всех предложенных ответом. Но мы разбираем случай, когда один человек пишет все. Касательно "подконтрольности" - я написал выше, что надуманно. Не будет клиент (пользователь) себе что-то менять.Если пытаются взломать - чужие данные все равно под защитой, а свои пусть портят сколько влезет

Comment: @RostislavDugin ваше «проверяется сервером» на практике скорее всего всё равно приведёт к тому, что бизнес-логика фактически окажется на сервере. Теоретизировать без конкретных примеров проектов я дальше не могу и засим наверное закругляюсь

Comment: @andreymal, "скорее всего" - все же предположение. Но спасибо за обсуждение! Ваш вариант про большое количество клиентов с разной бизнес-логикой - действительно подошел. Если есть желание, добавьте в ответ, пожалуйста. А я пойду Вам комментарии пролайкаю в знак благодарности что ли)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Тебе понадобится сервер с row level security. Потому что если без - все проверки и ограничения на клиенте будут бесполезны. Клиент заведомо неподконтролен, любой мамкин хакер возьмет curl и отправит запрос на твой сервер для получения не предназначенных ему данных.
2. В случае наличия полноценного backend ты можешь регулировать всё что захочешь - кэширование, балансировка, аутентификация разными методами и другие ручки, которые не будут доступны тебе, если клиент будет напрямую лазить в БД. Потому что см. п.1 - обязательно и очень быстро найдутся желающие потрогать СУБД поплотнее в части не принадлежащих им данных. По сути бакенд это изоляция клиента от конкретной реализации механизмов обработки и хранения. Имея бакенд ты можешь делать клиентов на разных языках и платформах, которые смогут использовать одно и то же API. И все обновления бакенда никак не повлияют на клиентов, потому что у них есть API.
3. Представляется некоторые сложности с логированием в случае прямого доступа к СУБД. Кто какие запросы отправил, где, кто и когда что поменял.

Answer (score 2):

1. Раскрывается структура БД для конечного пользователя.
2. Жесткая привязка всей программы к конкретной структуре БД. Нельзя переименовать поле таблицы, разделить или объединить таблицы, вынести какие-либо данные в другие БД (например, с целями кеширования) без поиска и изменения всех мест где есть использование затронутых структур.
3. Подозреваю, что избыточное дублирование кода в разных частях такой программы и усложнение чтения кода. Вместо GET /user/{id} надо писать полноценный SQL запрос да еще в нестандартном виде.
4. Привязка к одной СУБД, нельзя написать еще одну "прослойку" для другой базы, которая внешне реализует те же методы что и первая, но внутри использует совсем другую БД. Как был у неё get(users) так и остался, но внутри совсем другая обработка.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! По пунктам: 1 - она и так раскрывается, если просмотреть обращения к серверу. 2 - почему нельзя? Изменяем поле БД и изменяем логику в клиенте. Абсолютно также мы бы сделали бы с сервером. 3. - мы бы и так делали бы это с сервером. 4. - да, но специфический кейс. Также, как бы мы переписали сервер под новую СУБД, мы перепишем и клиент. **Вывод:** собственно, принципиальных различий нет. Но сейчас немного дополню вопрос, чтобы была вводная "пишет все один разработчик".

Comment: @RostislavDugin 1 - нет, не раскрывается, сервер может вернуть абсолютно что угодно и это совсем не обязательно совпадает со структурой БД; 4 - нет, не специфический, многие проекты перезжают с одной БД на другую в процессе эволюции, и многие проекты используют несколько разных БД одновременно

Comment: 1 - так или иначе, пользователь все равно получает данные. Ничего полезного из этих данных извлечь нельзя. 4 - абсолютно также к клиенту привяжем эти базы. Были изменения на сервере => стали изменения в клиенте. Кол-во кода осталось то же.

Comment: @RostislavDugin 1 - эти данные могут быть творчески переработаны сервером так, что не будут нести никакой информации о структуре БД (кроме того, БД может в принципе отсутствовать); 4 - это сработает, только если у вас один клиент и он полностью ваш и обновляется одномоментно везде. Если вы ВКонтакте и у вас уже есть миллионы неподконтрольных вам клиентов — обновить все клиенты будет очень, ОЧЕНЬ, **ООООООООЧЕНЬ** сложно. Собственно, ВКонтакте их не может обновить уже с десяток лет.

Comment: @andreymal, 1 - так мы же не структуру БД скрываем, а скорее данные, которые храним (зачем пользователю, например, значит, что мы знаем о его месте проживания). 4. Вот, это уже ближе к теме. Вопрос поддержки большого кол-ва клиентов! Самое весомое, как по мне. Но мы говорим о кейсе, когда 1 разработчик все делает. То есть, у нас один клиент. Так что тоже как "аргумент против" - не подойдет...

Comment: @RostislavDugin 1. Бывают варианты когда getuser(id) может возвращать разные набор полей в зависимости от того кто, когда и откуда её вызывает. Одним оно вернет только имя, другим имя и баланс по счету, третьим всю информацию о пользователе. И какие базы оно при этом опрашивает известно только писавшему эту прослойку.

2 и 3. Данные пользователя могут понадобится в десятке мест - везде нужно будет переписывать. Вместо одного getuser(id), а это лишние ошибки и опечатки в тексте.

4. Теряется легкость перехода. Вместо одного изменения "эта или та прослойка" надо менять по всему клиенту.

Comment: @Morewind, 1 - возможно, но я обычно делаю API со списком полей выборки. Несущественно, в общем. 2 и 3 - почему? Мы же всегда запрашиваем конкретный список полей для отображения. И если нам придет больше полей, потому что сервер так решил - нам это без разницы. 4 - тоже не согласен. Везде запрашивается конкретный список полей. Ничего не измениться.

Comment: Если программа небольшая, для одного пользователя и пишется одним програмистом - то конечно, это возможно излишество. С другой стороны меня был случай когда надо было написать просмотр на веб заказов в ресторане из существующей учетной программы (в которой этого не было). Там что бы получить простой спикок "дата, номер, сумма, список блюд с ценами" требовался весьма сложный запрос. Писать его каждый раз везде где он нужен правильно заполняя параметры было бы очень сложно. А так писал getReceiptList(datе), getReceipt(id) и горя не знал.